# Der Unterschied zwischen aufstehen and aufwachen

Tags: word-choice

was ist der unterschied zwischen diese zwei sätze?

> Um halb 7 bin ich  aufgewacht
>
> Um halb 7 bin ich aufgestanden

Sind aufwachen und aufstehen austauschbar ?

Antwortet sie bitte auf Englisch

Comment: Every german-english dictionary would give you the answer.

Comment: yeah of course they do ... but i couldn't find anything

Comment: @snowpatrol You can use [dict.leo.org](http://dict.leo.org), that is a very good German-English dictionary. For example: [aufwachen](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_en.html#/search=aufwachen&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on).

Comment: Linguee.com is also good: http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=aufwachen

Comment: [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/) is another good one.

Answer (score 5):

- *Aufwachen* means *stop sleeping*
- *Aufstehen* means leaving the bed (i. e. finally for that night, not only to fetch a glass of water)

Of course there is the type of people, where these occur at the same time, but for others there may be hours in between.

Comment: It's the same in English. *wake up* vs *get out of bed*